# Relative frequency histogram plot of a numeric variable in massive dataset

Tags: r, histogram, percentage, numeric

I have a numerical variable `"myvariable"` of `14e^06 elements` which I want to plot a histogram to show the relative frequency of each bin.

Considering the following sample data:

```
set.seed(1234)
wdata = data.frame(
        sex = factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
        weight = c(rnorm(200, 55), rnorm(200, 58)))
```

We can plot the normal frequency histogram:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(wdata, aes(x = weight)) +
        geom_histogram(aes(color = sex))
```

Or we can plot the **histogram of the relative frequency**

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(wdata, aes(x = weight)) +
 geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))
```

Now, considering my real data:

```
temp <- c(291L, 2440L, 1317L, 67L, 2258L, 3992L, 202L, 224L, 6761L, 9671L, 
+        218L, 4609L, 2173L, 5691L, 39296L)
myvariable <- sample(temp, 14000000, replace = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)
mydf <- data.frame(myvariable)
    ggplot(mydf, aes(x = myvariable)) +
     geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))
```

The process of plotting a relative frequency histogram become infinitely slow, therefore, the only alternative would be to plot with geom_density but it is not what I need.

My question is: 
Can you suggest me a better approach in order to obtain the relative frequency histogram of my numeric variable?

Comment: thank you for the edit. Is the question clear or I can improve it to receive asnwers?